# Organize files in folders corresponding to subs in a module in vba

Tags: excel, vba

im working on a custom "Library" of sorts in vba, because otherwise i would program it over and over again. For example an Errorhandler or standard stuff like swap, sort or pathfinding algorithms. For better highlighting i do the writing in VSCode and just copy paste it into VBA. After some time this became tedious so i got XVBA, which helps significantly. I have ordered my files in folders, which correspond to a Module in VBA and the files are the Subprocedures. Using XVBA i havent found a way how i can create 1 Module (The Foldername) to put in all Subprocedures (Files)?

I would like to prefer to keep the files seperated for better overview and not merge them into one big .bas / .frm / .cls file. I would also prefer to not have so many modules for the same reason.

Comment: https://rubberduckvba.com/

Comment: Btw there is a way for me to use code to create merge the files in the folder into a single .bas file but if there is a simpler way i would prefer that one